How to get int(R G B) color value from guchar *pixel in Gtk4?
I'm trying to create a color picker widget in gtk4, but I'm having trouble getting the pixel's rgb color value in integer format. It should take a pixel from the x*y position of a drawing area and convert the value to an integer. Can anyone check it?
check it---
//pick int rgb from pixel (not working)

    int aa, gg, bb;
    static void
    get_pixel (GdkPixbuf *pixbuf, int x, int y)
    {
      int width = gdk_pixbuf_get_width (pixbuf);
      int height = gdk_pixbuf_get_height (pixbuf);

      if ((x >= 0 && x < width) && (y >= 0 && y < height)){

           gint rowstride, n_channels;
           guchar *pixels, *p;

           n_channels = gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels (pixbuf);
           rowstride = gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride (pixbuf);
           pixels = gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels (pixbuf);

           p = pixels + y * rowstride + x * n_channels;
           aa = p[0];
           gg = p[1];
           bb = p[2];
           printf("Pixel Col: %d x %d | %u %u %u %u\n", x, y, p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3]);

      }
    }

//pixbuf holding mesh gradient

    GdkPixbuf *get_gradientData (int w, int h, 
                                 guchar r, 
                                 guchar g, 
                                 guchar b, 
                                 guchar a)
    {
        cairo_t *cr;
        cairo_surface_t* tgt;
        cairo_pattern_t *pattern;

        tgt = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, w, h);
        cr = cairo_create(tgt);

       //`````draw pattern (color gradient)````

        GdkPixbuf *out = gdk_pixbuf_get_from_surface (tgt, 0, 0, w, h);
        cairo_surface_destroy(tgt);
        cairo_destroy(cr);
        return out;
    }

//draw gradient on cr

    int r=1, g=0, b=0;
    static void
    draw_function (GtkDrawingArea *area,
                   cairo_t        *cr,
                   int             width,
                   int             height,
                   gpointer        data)
    {
        GdkPixbuf *p = get_gradientData (width, height, r, g, b, 1.0); //r, g, b, a

        //````transfer pixbuf to cr```

        cairo_paint (cr);
        g_object_unref (p);
    }


//mouse click event get x y position

    static void click_pos_on_button_release (GtkGesture *click,
                                             int n_press,
                                             gdouble x,
                                             gdouble y,
                                             gpointer user_data)
    {

          //get mouse pointerx y position 
            g_print ("Clicked pos: %0.0f  %0.0f\n", x, y);
            GdkPixbuf *p = get_gradientData(270, 270, r, g, b, 1.0); //r, g, b, a
            get_pixel (p, x, y);
            g_object_unref (p);
            printf("Pixel:%d x %d | %d %d %d\n", x, y, aa, gg,bb);

    }

// main function
    static void
    activate (GtkApplication* app,
              gpointer        user_data)
    {
      GtkWidget *area = gtk_drawing_area_new();

      gtk_drawing_area_set_draw_func (GTK_DRAWING_AREA (area),
                                  draw_function,
                                  NULL, NULL);

      GtkGesture *gesture_click = gtk_gesture_click_new ();
      g_signal_connect (gesture_click, "pressed", G_CALLBACK(click_pos_on_button_release), area);

      gtk_widget_show (window);
    }


If inside your get_pixel function you print the correct values, then you don't have a problem getting the pixels. You don't show when and where you are printing the wrong content. You might print them before you even called your function but without getting a MCVE we cannot tell you what is wrong.

I checked it, the result inside the get_pixel function is also wrong. The question has been edited.

Still, without a MCVE we cannot tell what is wrong. When and how do you call that function? You might be calling the function before your DrawingArea was actually drawn to. From what origin do you count x and y?

please check, question has been edited due to @MCVE. main issue unable to  get correct result(rgba value) in int format.

I have now put the programme in a running state. In addition to some outdated functions, I have especially tied the event controller to the drawing area.
Also the applications window is created and added the drawing area to it.
I hope, you can continue there now.
#include<gtk/gtk.h>

 int aa, gg, bb;
    static void
    get_pixel (GdkPixbuf *pixbuf, int x, int y)
    {
      int width = gdk_pixbuf_get_width (pixbuf);
      int height = gdk_pixbuf_get_height (pixbuf);

      if ((x >= 0 && x < width) && (y >= 0 && y < height)){

           gint rowstride, n_channels;
           guchar *pixels, *p;

           n_channels = gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels (pixbuf);
           rowstride = gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride (pixbuf);
           pixels = gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels (pixbuf);

           p = pixels + y * rowstride + x * n_channels;
           aa = p[0];
           gg = p[1];
           bb = p[2];
           printf("Pixel Col: %d x %d | %u %u %u %u\n", x, y, p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3]);

      }
    }

//pixbuf holding mesh gradient

    GdkPixbuf *get_gradientData (int w, int h,
                                 guchar r,
                                 guchar g,
                                 guchar b,
                                 guchar a)
    {
        cairo_t *cr;
        cairo_surface_t* tgt;
        cairo_pattern_t *pattern;

        tgt = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, w, h);
        cr = cairo_create(tgt);

       //`````draw pattern (color gradient)````

        GdkPixbuf *out = gdk_pixbuf_get_from_surface (tgt, 0, 0, w, h);
        cairo_surface_destroy(tgt);
        cairo_destroy(cr);
        return out;
    }

//draw gradient on cr

    int r=1, g=0, b=0;
    static void
    draw_function (GtkDrawingArea *area,
                   cairo_t        *cr,
                   int             width,
                   int             height,
                   gpointer        data)
    {
        GdkPixbuf *p = get_gradientData (width, height, r, g, b, 1.0); //r, g, b, a

        //````transfer pixbuf to cr```

        cairo_paint (cr);
        g_object_unref (p);
    }


//mouse click event get x y position

    static void click_pos_on_button_release (GtkGesture *click,
                                             int n_press,
                                             gdouble x,
                                             gdouble y,
                                             gpointer user_data)
    {

          //get mouse pointerx y position
            g_print ("Clicked pos: %0.0f  %0.0f\n", x, y);
            GdkPixbuf *p = get_gradientData(270, 270, r, g, b, 1.0); //r, g, b, a
            get_pixel (p, x, y);
            g_object_unref (p);
            printf("Pixel:%f x %f | %d %d %d\n", x, y, aa, gg,bb);  // changed %d->%f

    }

// main function
    static void
    activate (GtkApplication* app,
              gpointer        user_data)
    {

    GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
  
    GtkWidget *area = gtk_drawing_area_new(); // new

      gtk_drawing_area_set_draw_func (GTK_DRAWING_AREA (area),
                                  draw_function,
                                  NULL, NULL);

      GtkGesture *gesture_click = gtk_gesture_click_new ();
      gtk_widget_add_controller(area,GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER(gesture_click));  // new
      g_signal_connect (gesture_click, "pressed", G_CALLBACK(click_pos_on_button_release), area);

      gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window),area);
      gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW(window));
    }

/* new */
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    app = gtk_application_new("holger.gtk.pixbuf",G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS); 
    g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION(app),argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);

    return status;
}

Please feel free to ask a new question for further problems.
Have fun programming.
